# In Kotlin How to set default param value in Koin

Tags: kotlin, koin

I have a Kotlin class with default params defined.

```
Class ACheck(val name:String,val check:boolean =false)
```

To create a class:

```
factory { (name:String, check: Boolean) -> ACheck(name,check) }
```

To use:

```
Get<ACheck>{parametersOf(“somenname”,true)}
Get<ACheck>{parametersOf(“somenname”,false)}
```

Do we have anything like this in Koin. Don’t find anything like this

```
factory { (name:String, check: Boolean=false) -> ACheck(name,check) }
```

Comment: What's your definition of `factory` and `Get`? What are you trying to achieve in the last statement? It doesn't make much sense to provide a default value here, since `factory` is the one calling the passed lambda, and will most likely always provide it. Default values only really make sense on the API surface for users.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
factory { (name: String) -> ACheck(name, false) } // ACheck(name)
```

And then:

```
Get<ACheck>{ parametersOf("somenname") }
```

?